# How to iterate through multiple lists to return a tuple with good syntax

Tags: python, iteration

I would like to write this code in the neatest way possible:

```
def test_roomVolume(self):
        widths = [4, 1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1]
        lengths = [4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1]
        heights = [4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1]
        expected = [64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        for i in range(len(widths)):
            dimensions = (widths[i], lengths[i], heights[i])
```

Is there a better way to create the dimensions tuple? Like

```
dimensions = (widths, lengths, heights)[i]
```

Something like that?

Comment: See the linked question. `zip` works with any number of lists, not just two.